# Problems which can be formulated as a quadratic programming problem

Tags: machine-learning, optimization

I am currently searching for a number of algorithms which can be formulated as a quadratic programming problem. Particularly I am looking for such ones like the support vector machine which can are resulting in a minimization under constraints. I would be glad about any other problem suggestions from statistics/machine learning.